# How do you split in beautiful soup based on two parameters - python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beutifulsoup to extract the address of images in a documents. The links in the document however need cleaning, (specifically most images have links like /image.jpg&randomtext and I want in formation https://www.webaddress.com/image.jpg&filetype=l"
for this I currently use the code below:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

    c = ' <html>
            <img src="/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.jpg&filetype=h" width="300" height="300" alt="imagesk"/>
            <img src="/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.JPG&filetype=h" width="300" height="300" alt="imagesk"/> '

    soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
    link = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img')]                                  
    link = [link_temp.split('.jpg')[0] for link_temp in link]                       
    full_images_links = ["https://www.webaddress.com" + linktemp + ".jpg&filetype=l" for linktemp in link]
```

this basically searches for all the linked images that end in .jpg, removes the content after it (lots of random codes), and then formats in way I can get the images.

This works fine when the images has got the extension ".jpg", however does not when it has the extension ".JPG"

For the above example, the desired output for the first image file works fine and gives:

```
  https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.jpg&filetype=l
```

however the second one, the code comes out as

```
  https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.JPG&filetype=h.jpg&filetype=l
```

because it does split based on the capitalized ".JPG"

I am ideally looking for something that could be extended to work with different formats (e.g. may run into .JPEG, .jpeg etc)

Comment: Could you elaborate a nice reproduceable example including an example input and the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: I have added an example input. The desired output for the first image file works fine (i.e. https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.jpg&filetype=l)however the second one, the code comes out as "https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.JPG&filetype=h.jpg&filetype=l"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can extract the filename from the URL using [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module:

```
base_url = "https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename={filename}&filetype=l"
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

print [base_url.format(filename=urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(img['src']).query)['filename'][0])
       for img in soup.find_all('img')]
```

Prints:

```
[
    'https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=swc.jpg&filetype=l',
    'https://www.webaddress.com/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.JPG&filetype=l'
]
```

Note that this would work for any image file extension. We are just extracting the filenames and pasting them into a placeholder in a new URL using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split each link. Allows you to ignore the case and account for the different jpg/jpeg alternatives easily.

Setup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

c = """ 
<html>
        <img src="/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.jpg&&filetype=h" width="300" height="300" alt="imagesk"/>
        <img src="/url/urls.do?filename=SWC.JPG&&filetype=h" width="300" height="300" alt="imagesk"/> 
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
link = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img')]
```

Using regex:

```
import re

extracted_links = [re.split(r'\.jpg|\.jpeg', item, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
                   for item in link]
extracted_links
Out[11]: ['/url/urls.do?filename=SWC', '/url/urls.do?filename=SWC']
```

Regex can look like gobbledegook if you're not familiar with it, but this one's
pretty simple: `a|b` means "a or b", and then `.` has a special meaning in regexes
so you need to escape it with a backslash.